# react-native-video 5.2.0 Android Build error RNC 0.66.3

Tags: typescript, react-native

**Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.13.2**
this error shows every time I tried to build in android. IOS work fine for me.

I added jcenter to **android/build.gradle** like this:

```js
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .... # rest of your code
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have faced the same error! But I don't get any **perfect solution!**
I use a hacky solution. You may try it for saving your time!

So first of all you have to go through with the documentation.
After adding all the extra code you have to go

**`Project Root folder: node_modules/react-native-video`**
in

> package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    ...
    "shaka-player": "^3.2.1" // Add this line
},
```

Next: go to

**`/android-exoplayer/build.gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
   - implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.13.2') { // delete this line
   + implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.13.3') {  // add this line
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    ...
    ...

   - implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.13.2') { // delete this line
   + implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.13.3') { // add this line
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
}
```

**save it! And run your project again!**

> **Note:** This will not work if you delete your node_modules folder (You have to add it again for working properly)
> I think this solution will be added in the next release of
> **react-native-video**

Hope you are good to go!